# HTML, PHP Multiple multi Select fields in one array issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem that i have no clue to how explain, but i'll try my best.

I have a select field form where i can dynamically add more if needed.

```
Person 1: Select your allergies
          1.Nut
          2.Gluten
          3.No meat....
```

At this point the user presses the + button to add another person

```
Person 2: Select Allergies
          1.Nut
          2.Gluten
          3.Meat
```

The bottom is my HTML

```
<select name="s_allergies[]" class="form-control" multiple>

            <option value="none" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
            <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
            <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
            <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
            <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
            <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
            <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>

</select>
```

I'm following this code to process the form (works for all other fields) but for some reason, the multi select field only outputs one value even if two or more are selected.

```
if(!empty($_POST['s_fname'])){ //checks if an additional attendee has been added

    $s_fname = $_POST['s_fname'];
    $s_lname = $_POST['s_lname'];
    $s_title = $_POST['s_title'];
    $s_type = $_POST['s_type'];
    $s_celebration = $_POST['s_celebration'];
    $s_allergies = $_POST['s_allergies'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($s_fname); $i++){

        if(!empty($s_fname[$i])){

            $sfname = escape($s_fname[$i]);
            $slname = escape($s_lname[$i]);
            $stitle = escape($s_title[$i]);
            $stype = escape($s_type[$i]);
            $scelebration = escape($s_celebration[$i]);
            $sallergies = escape(implode(",", $s_allergies[$i]));

            //query to insert to attendee database
            echo "$sfname $slname $stitle $stype $scelebration $sallergies";

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here's an image [image]
EDIT2:
When dumping the variable, this is what i get.. it seems to be putting everything in one array? For the first field, i selected Gluten and Nut, for the second person i selected Shellfish and Lactose.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Gluten
    [1] => Nut
    [2] => Shellfish
    [3] => Lactose
)
```

Comment: did you try to dump the $_POST to see how you are receiving the data?

Comment: `Array
    (
        [0] => Gluten
        [1] => Nut
        [2] => Shellfish
        [3] => Lactose
    )` This is what gets dumped with print_r()

Comment: The problem is, the multiple select is already an array, and so `s_allergies` brings every item selected in the same array, you'll need to modify the names to something like `s_allergies[1][]`, `s_allergies[2][]` and so on

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any index name same as `select`

```
<?php

//check other values here 
foreach ($_POST['s_allergies'] as $alg){
 //your poerations here
}
?>
```

if you use more than one select box you have to give separate  name to it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have something like:

```
    <select name="s_allergies[1][]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="none" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
            <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
            <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
            <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
            <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
            <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
            <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
</select>
<select name="s_allergies[2][]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="none" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
            <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
            <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
            <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
            <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
            <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
            <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
</select>
<select name="s_allergies[3][]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="none" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
            <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
            <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
            <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
            <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
            <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
            <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
</select>
<select name="s_allergies[4][]" class="form-control" multiple>
            <option value="none" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
            <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
            <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
            <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
            <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
            <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
            <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
</select>
```

and then you can access each multiple select as an array. The output would look like

```
  's_allergies' => 
array (size=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Gluten' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Nut' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Shellfish' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Gluten' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Lactose' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Egg' (length=3)
      3 => string 'Vegetarian' (length=10)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Nut' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Egg' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Vegetarian' (length=10)
      3 => string 'Vegetarian with Seafood' (length=23)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Shellfish' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Lactose' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Egg' (length=3)
      3 => string 'Vegetarian' (length=10)
```

Comment: looks like i wont be able to use this, since im using a template to add more fields. and the template is going to copy [1][] over and over again.